# GetGenericTypeDefinition returns different types

Tags: c#, inheritance, types, type-systems

Given that I have the following types

```
interface IMyInterface<T> { }
class MyClass<T> : IMyInterface<T> { }
```

How come the following 5 lines doesn't produce the same outcome?

```
var type1 = typeof(IMyInterface<>);
var type2 = typeof(IMyInterface<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition();
var type3 = typeof(MyClass<>).GetInterfaces().Single();
var type4 = typeof(MyClass<object>).GetInterfaces().Single().GetGenericTypeDefinition();
var type5 = typeof(MyClass<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetInterfaces().Single();
```

type1, type2 & type4 are the same

type3 & type5 are the same

Comment: On your second line of text you say they aren't the same on the last line you tell us all five variables are the same? They will all probably return the type of the interface as that is what you are asking it to return..

Comment: In type3 you should get an instantiated generic interface type with T bound to MyClass'es T. That they have the same name is coincidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of 3 and five, it **is** a different type; it is the `IMyInterface<SpecificT>` where `SpecificT` is the **generic type parameter** (not the actual known *value*, but the parameter itself) from `MyClass<T>` - i.e. it is dependent.

This is different to the completely free (independent) `T` in `IMyInterface<T>`, which is what 1, 2 and 4 provide.

If you rename the Ts, it becomes more obvious:

```
interface IMyInterface<TA> { }
class MyClass<TB> : IMyInterface<TB> { }
```

Now check the `.GetGenericArguments().Single().Name` against each. For 1, 2 and 4 it is `TA`. For 3 and 5 it is `TB`.

Comment: ok, is the a way to make this "pass"?
`typeof(MyClass<>).GetInterfaces().Single().??? == typeof(IMyInterface<>)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Marc Gravell, here is some extra work to point out the differences:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace test {
  class Program {
    interface IMyInterface<T> { }
    class MyClass<T> : IMyInterface<T> { }

    private static void Print(Type xType) {
      unsafe {
        fixed (char* c = xType.Name) {
          long lAddress = (long)c;
          Console.WriteLine(lAddress);
        }
      }
    } //

    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Type type1 = typeof(IMyInterface<>);
      Type type2 = typeof(IMyInterface<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition();
      Type type3 = typeof(MyClass<>).GetInterfaces().Single();
      Type type4 = typeof(MyClass<object>).GetInterfaces().Single().GetGenericTypeDefinition();
      Type type5 = typeof(MyClass<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetInterfaces().Single();

      Print(type1); // 34060364
      Print(type2); // 34060364
      Print(type3); // 34062812
      Print(type4); // 34060364
      Print(type5); // 34062812     

      // therfore:
      // type1 == type2 == type4
      // and
      // type3 == type5

      Console.WriteLine("type1 == type2  " + type1.Equals(type2)); // true
      Console.WriteLine("type1 == type4  " + type1.Equals(type4)); // true
      Console.WriteLine("type2 == type4  " + type2.Equals(type4)); // true
      Console.WriteLine("type3 == type5  " + type3.Equals(type5)); // true

      Console.WriteLine("type1 == type5  " + type1.Equals(type5)); // false
      Console.WriteLine("type2 == type5  " + type2.Equals(type5)); // false
      Console.WriteLine("type4 == type5  " + type4.Equals(type5)); // false
      Console.WriteLine("type3 == type4  " + type3.Equals(type4)); // false
      Console.WriteLine("type1 == type3  " + type1.Equals(type3)); // false
      Console.WriteLine("type2 == type3  " + type2.Equals(type3)); // false

      // the names are the same, but the objects are not
      Console.WriteLine(type1.Name.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine(type2.Name.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine(type3.Name.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine(type4.Name.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine(type5.Name.ToString());            

 /* example output:
38778956
38778956
38781404
38778956
38781404
type1 == type2  True
type1 == type4  True
type2 == type4  True
type3 == type5  True
type1 == type5  False
type2 == type5  False
type4 == type5  False
type3 == type4  False
type1 == type3  False
type2 == type3  False
IMyInterface`1
IMyInterface`1
IMyInterface`1
IMyInterface`1
IMyInterface`1
*/

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

http://csharphardcoreprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/reflection-basics-advanced/