# Why a generic type definition implemented interfaces lose type information?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, equality

For example, if you run the following code...

```
Type IListType = new List<string>().GetType()
                                   .GetInterface("IList`1")
                                   .GetGenericTypeDefinition();
```

...and you watch `IListType` variable, you'll find that the whole `Type` instance has all properties available like `FullName` and others.

But what happens when you run the code bellow?

```
Type IListType2 = typeof(List<>).GetInterface("IList`1")
```

Now `IListType` got from a generic type definition isn't the same as the first code sample: most `Type` properties will return null.

The main issue with this is that `IListType == IListType2` doesn't equal while they're the same type.

What's going on?

### This is ugly...

Now see what happens if you call `IListType2.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`... It recovers the type information!

It would be great that a .NET Framework development team member could explain us why an *already generic type definition which has strangely lost its metadata* has `IsGenericTypeDefinition` property set to `false` while it's still a generic type definition, and finally, if you call `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` on it, you recover the type information.

### This is strange...

The following equality will be `true`:

```
Type IListType = new List<string>().GetType()
                        .GetInterface("IList`1")
                        .GetGenericTypeDefinition();

// Got interface is "like a generic type definition" since it has
// no type for T generic parameter, and once you call 
// GetGenericTypeDefinition() again, it recovers the lost metadata 
// and the resulting generic type definition equals the one got from
// List<string>!
Type IListType2 = typeof(List<>).GetInterface("IList`1").GetGenericTypeDefinition();

bool y = IListType == IListType2;
```

Comment: Isn't the first the runtime compiled (and typed) version of `IList` while the second is the generic 'untyped' one.

Comment: @PatrickHofman But I don't understand what has to do that with the fact that generic type definition of `IList<>` is, at the end of the day, *constant*....

Comment: Well, it isn't as you see... In fact it are two different interfaces.

Comment: You're not checking the same type. First one is the generic type definition of the `IList` type parameter while the second is the runtime type for `IList1`

Comment: because come on! this should be fair `typeof (List<>).GetInterface("IList1").GetGenericTypeDefinition()`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I'm not checking any type parameter.

Comment: I suspect `IListType.FullName` and `IListType2.FullName` is different

Comment: I meant generic type definition, sorry. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803939/getgenerictypedefinition-returns-different-types) will help.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya They're absolutely different: `IListType2.FullName` is `null` :D

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Check my update, I believe it will surprise you :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following types are all different and not connected by an inheritance relationship:

- `IList<T>`
- `IList<int>`
- `IList<string>`

All of these have different `Type` objects because you can do different things with them. The latter two are the specializations of the former. The first is the generic type definition (which you can obtain through `GetGenericTypeDefinition`).

There is another part to the explanation. When you say `class List<T> : IList<T>` then the `IList<T>` part is *not* equal to `typeof(IList<>)` because it is already specialized to `T`. This is no longer a generic type definition. It is a concrete type such as `IList<int>`. It is specialized to bind its only type argument to the `T` that `List<T>` was specialized to.

---

Experiment for LINQPad:

```
Type bound = new List<string>().GetType().GetInterface("IList`1");
bound.GenericTypeArguments.Single().Dump(); //string


Type bound = typeof(List<>).GetInterface("IList`1");
bound.GenericTypeArguments.Single().Dump(); //"T"
(bound.GenericTypeArguments.Single() == typeof(List<>).GetGenericArguments().Single()).Dump(); //true
```

Comment: That's why I though too. Can you check if my undeleted answer is correct (not asking to vote, just for my understanding).

Comment: Double check the issue, @PatrickHofman already answered the same conclusion and I believe he realized that it's not as easy as it seems to be...

Comment: @PatrickHofman didn't you just switch "first" and "second"? Otherwise seems correct.

Comment: I don't think so, the `new List<string>()` one (first) is the typed one, right? It is `IList<string>`.

Comment: @usr BTW, about your second conclusion, I'm not trying to use a concrete type definition as a generic type definition. If I'm not mistaken, I'm getting interfaces from a generic type definition, thus they're also generic type definitions unbound to any implementation detail...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer no, they are bound to the List's T. They are no longer customizable. If you implement multiple such interfaces all of them will have the same type arguments which is evidence they are bound. In any case, when you call `GetGenericTypeDefinition` this transitions back to the definition. @MatíasFidemraizer can you check whether this answers your question or not? It seems to me that it does.

Comment: With `GetGenericTypeDefinition` you get `IList'1`, but **with no** generic type arguments, with `typeof(List<>).GetInterface("IList'1")` you get `IList'1` **with** T as generic type argument

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer explain what's strange. GetGenericTypeDefinition transitions back to the definition which is always the same.

Comment: @usr What's strange for me is it has lost the metadata because the interface was got from a generic type definition.

Comment: Could you say that `T` is a placeholder type that is shared by the interfaces that `List<>` implements?

Comment: @usr: Your linqpad example isn't quite the same as the OP. In the example where `GetGenericTypeDefinition` isn't being called (as your example) no type is being provided for the list so it should be using the typeless one. Try it with the `IListType` or `IListType2` that the OP has and your generic type comes out as empty array and `typeof(T)`. It clearly shows that it isn't the generic but I'm not sure what `typeof(T)` means in this case...

Comment: Yes, a `Type` can also represent a generic type argument or parameter. `Type` can represent a lot of things.

Comment: @Chris it is not typeless, it is specialized to use the List's `T`. It's explained above. The type is still generic but closed (as opposed to open). Experiment 2 shows that.

Comment: @usr: my point was that the type is definitely not string. The comparison the OP is doing is `IList<T>` compared to `IList<>` (as I understand it) whereas your little linqpad example brings `IList<string>` into things which is not one of the OP's types in his two variables. Though I see your example is now updated which may have happened before I wrote my comment but I only just saw it. :)

Comment: @usr Maybe your explanation can be right, but I'm not 100% sure it answers the exposed issue. I don't see your LINQ Pad experiment demonstrate why the question's proposed code behave this way.

Comment: So calling `GetInterface` on a generic type does not give you a generic interface (as you would initially expect), but a concrete one (or rather a 'partially concrete' one, because it has a placeholder type argument). Makes sense when you think about it. `List<T>` implements, among others, `IList<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`. This behavior allows you to verify that both interfaces will specialize on the same type, even when that type is not known yet. And if you do need the generic type definitions of those interfaces, you can always call `GetGenericTypeDefinition` on them.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet exactly! This behavior is required to provide the information about this. If this info was erased/omitted you could not reflect about certain things. The C# compiler for example needs this info for type checks. It must know that two T's are the same or not.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Ok, let's assume this. Then whey the type itself loses basically more than 80% metadata. Even the `FullName`. What has to do this with the fact that it's a *partially concrete type*?

Comment: It looses the meta data that is not applicable, I'd say. FullName is null but Name is set (in the case I just looked at it was "T"). I think FullName is supposed to point at the point of definition and there is no type name syntax to specify this here.

Comment: @usr BTW, while I understand what you say and when I posted the Q&A my first thought was the same as you, I believe that the whole behavior is *quircky* and maybe not well documented. You may not expect non-generic type definitions of interfaces from a generic type definition.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I think the fact that closed generic types are returned is OK and actually required for certain use cases (for example, in IDictionary<T1, T2> you need to discern between T1 and T2). But the set of members returning null might well be quirky. The reflection API has it's problems... In other places, too.

Comment: @usr In the other hand, I still think that, when you call `GetGenericTypeDefinition` you expect to get an unbound type, because this is a good way to check if two types implement an interface like `IList<T>` when the whole types are generic type definitions already

Comment: GetGenericTypeDefinition always returns an unbound type to my knowledge. I have not seen a counter example to that in this thread. Is there one?

Comment: @usr Well, but I mean that the returned type is someway *bound* to the type from which the type definition was got from...  I believe `GetGenericTypeDefinition` should always return the same type definition. This is why you call it, maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: @usr Well, it's not bound to the source type, I mean that its partial state is, at the end of the day, quircky.

Comment: What you are getting is `IList<T2>` or `T2` in `interface IList<T1>; class List<T2> : IList<T2>`. Here, I used a distinct name for each distinct type which should make it more clear.

Comment: @usr I would re-phrase your answer to explain the part of interfaces are got in a quircky/partial types. I believe that it's not an explanation at all, but basically is the way .NET works during run-time. It's just a design/architecture decision, isn't it?

Comment: I think this all makes sense. A graph diagram would clear this up. The nodes are the types and the directed edges are method calls on types. Maybe you should draw such a diagram and post it for review. I think your understanding is still not 100% complete.

Comment: @usr It is. In fact, for example, `typeof(List<>).GetGenericArguments()[0] != typeof(IList<>).GetGenericArguments()[0]`. Even when `List<>` implements `IList<>`, `T` won't equal.

Comment: @usr Anyway, I still think that the whole behavior it's not 100% coherent, but we could discuss it during a year and, at the end of the day, as I said in other comment, it's just a design decision made by the .NET devteam. Of course, they did because of some actual requirement.

Answer (score 2):

The first version of `IList<T>` is the actual typed version of `IList<T>`, let's say `IList<string>`.

The second one is the generic definition of `IList<T>` without a type for `T`.

That makes the two interfaces different. There are not the same, since the first is a concrete version of the second.

Comment: Check the last call in the chain in the first code sample: `.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`

Comment: You assume the generic type definition of the first is the same as the second code block, which it isn't.

Comment: I believe that your answer isn't very clear about the reason of the whole difference. If you get a generic type definition is because you don't care about the actual type.

Comment: Thanks for the effort anyway, I've marked usr as the "right" answer because of the more detailed explanation, BTW, both answers have the same implicit content. As I commented out on usr's answer, I still think that this is a quircky behavior and it can't be 100% explained without being an actual .NET devteam member, because there're some design decisions that may be ok for some reasons, but it still produces some unexpected behaviors :)